# Livestreaming audio get metadata

Tags: google-cast

With the help of this forum I have my app playing on chromecast now.  I am trying to figure out how or if it is possible to retrieve the live streaming audio metadata and display it on my tv.  I am using the default media player/receiver and the Cast Companion Library.
The sample cast video app does not play a live stream.  I have had no luck trying to figure out how to implement this.  For now I am just displaying a static message, but I know the users will complain and will want the live song info.

Answer (score 1):

As far as providing metadata, there is no difference between live or buffered streams; you provide the metadata in the same MediaInfo object and load that for your receiver.

Comment: Ok. This helps, I thought the cast device had its own retriever.  So then I guess I would need to create a service that would run when the user is casting that would keep checking for new metadata from the live stream.  Correct?  So then what method or callback can I use to send the new metadata to the receiver?

Comment: Hi Joeb, did you find a solution to this?